# ssrs GetTotal() Puplic Function

Tags: reporting-services, subtotal

I browsed for solution of total for ReportItem! + ReportItem! and found Puplic Function

```
Public Shared Value as Decimal =0
  Public Shared Function GetValue(Item as Decimal ) as Decimal 
     value= value + Item
     return Item
  End Function

Public Shared Function GetTotal()
     return value
  End Function
```

I use it on my column, and in report view all number count is right (last column is total)

[image: last column is total]

But. When I export it to Excel I get in that total field different numbers, sometimes it gets * by 4, sometimes by 2, It is random.

[image: excel total]

Can someone explain please, why that happening and if there some solution for that. Thanks!

I have a groups (there no detail for this field, only part and project grouping)
[image]

And the top grouping using GetValue(ReportItems!Value1 - ReportItems!Value2)
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your expression using the custom code?

Comment: Hello! Of course, added in the initial post

Comment: You are right about page breaks and shared, I hope I found something solving both

Comment: May be the solution will be just Keep Together: - True in the properties for this table...And keep it all in one page... It initially all with toggles up to project, so...

Comment: Seems that when the variable is shared and you go back and forward between pages, the variable continues to increase (re-executes the expression)

Comment: I think I will just get rid of shared, and force the report to appear only on one page, that seems to do the trick.

Comment: I have reworked my solution, check if it fixes your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the same expression running multiple times, you can use shared variables combined with a shared list.

In the list you store keys (group combinations) for which you have already run the expression.

If the key does not exist you add the value to the variable and add the key to the list.

Add the following custom code

```
Public shared value as Decimal =0

Public shared group1 As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)

Public  Function GetValue(Group as String, Item as Decimal ) as Decimal 
     If group1.Contains(Group) = False
     group1.add(Group)
     value= value + Item
     End If
     return Item
  End Function

Public Function GetTotal()
     return value
  End Function
```

Your expression should look like that below

```
= Code.GetValue(Fields!group1.Value & " " & Fields!group2.Value, ReportItems!value1.value - ReportItems!value2.value)
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much! It worked...But I read somewhere that values becoming zero when new page starting, and helping to add shared, that's why it was there initially... Is it true, and If i have more than one page, total wont count properly, and will set to zero with every new page?

Comment: Sorry for a long answer, weekends. That works.. became a little bit more complex, but works perfectly.  Thank you very much!